# Mail not going through : Sendmail Issue

Tags: email, sendmail

Some of the mails for a particular domain are not getting delivered from our mail server. We are using sendmail for mail server.

Fallowing can be seen in log

```
Oct 21 13:24:59 mailser sendmail[5407]: r9L7st1a005405: to=<subhra@test.in>, delay=00:00:03, xdelay=00:00:03, mailer=esmtp, pri=120539, relay=mailgw.test.in. [164.X.X.19], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (ok:  Message 289953693 accepted)
```

FOr other domains like yahoo , gmail  etc it is working fine .

But if I send the mail through commandline using mailx command from the same server , the message is going through...

```
Oct 21 13:30:37 ssdgweb sendmail[5443]: r9L80RFI005440: to=<subhra@test.in>, ctladdr=<user@server.example.in> (502/502), delay=00:00:10, xdelay=00:00:10, mailer=esmtp, pri=120329, relay=mailgw.test.in. [164.X.X.19], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (ok:  Message 289955601 accepted)
```

Please let us know what is the issue and how it can be resolved .

Comment: Both your log extracts show the exact same thing - "stat=Sent (ok:  Message 289953693 accepted).

Comment: yeah..same logs are getting generated..first log entry is from Application and second log entry is from command-line . But mails from commandline are going through . Not sure what is the issue or it is at the remote server end

Comment: @ZamaQues Have you inspected the log files at mailgw.test.in?

Comment: mailgw.test.in  is administered by a different domain . Just want to make sure that the issue is not from our end before we ask them to take a look.

Comment: Since the mail is delivered to the next system, but it doesn't get to its final destination, your next step must be to check the logs in that system. I would guess that you will find that the From:-address is misconfigured so that the sending domain doesn't exist. But you will need to see the logs from the next system to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved . The user-name used in "From:"  address generated by our application is somehow getting dropped at remote end. Changed the user-name and mails are going through now. Since we don't have access to the other mail server , could not locate the exact error message.

Since initially mails were going through command-line , I tried to drop mail from command-line using the "From:" address that was used by our application . We found that mails are not delivered if we use similar "From:" address generated by our application. This provided us to clue to resolve the issue.